# jQuery, AJAX, mySQL via PHP: Works in PC Chrome, not in IE, Safari, or Mac Chrome

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm writing an online Computer aided dispatching system for security companies, and I'm an amateur coder. High goal, I'm aware. I have a number of AJAX functions that work fine in PC based Chrome, but fail to complete or behave strangely in IE 11, Mac Chrome, and Safari. I'm using Bootstrap CSS, in case the class attributes seem strange.

In one case, I have a table or persons who have matched a set of query parameters. The match table has rows with buttons in each row:

```
<input class="btn btn-success" value="Add Existing Person" onClick="AddExistingPerson('<?php echo $_SESSION['ESN'];?>','<?php echo $row['PersonID'];?>')">
```

`$_SESSION ['ESN']` is the index of the Call for Service event

`$row['PersonID']` is the index on the persons table pulled from the array returned by the person search query.

Here's the called Java function:

```
function AddExistingPerson(ESN,PersonID) {
  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: '../CAD/ajax.php',
      data:{action:'AddExistingPerson',esn:ESN,personid:PersonID},
      success:function(html) {
         return (html);
       }

  });
  //refresh();
  parent.window.location.reload(true);
  window.close();
}
```

Ajax.php excerpt below:

```
switch ($_POST['action']) {
    case "AddExistingPerson":
        phpAddExistingPerson($_POST['esn'],$_POST['personid']);
        break;
}

function phpAddExistingPerson($ESN,$PersonID){
    $link = dbConnect($_SESSION['dbName']); //handles my db connection. no problems with this
    $qryAddExistingPerson = 'INSERT INTO `tblEventPersons` (`ESN`,`PersonID`,`Role`) VALUES (' . $ESN . ',' . $PersonID . ',7);';
    $rstAddExistingPerson = mysqli_query($link,$qryAddExistingPerson);
}
```

After this executes, the window with the matches table is supposed to close, and the persons table in the CAD event window is supposed to refresh, showing the new party added.

Most of the time, except in PC Chrome where there's no issue, I can't even get the select window to close. It certainly doesn't add the record to tblEventPersons.

I've pulled up the monitors with right click, inspect element. I'm not getting any errors shown. I'm not sure how to proceed as I'm not sure how to find where the dysfunction even lies.

Thanks for any direction, -Chris.

Comment: Is there any error shown in Developer Console?

Comment: _“I'm writing an online Computer Aided Dispatching system for security companies, and I'm an amateur coder. High goal, I'm aware.”_ – So this is purely for educational purposes, and not for production use in the real world then?

Comment: The function you use is written in JavaScript, not Java. And your current Ajax.php code is vulnerable to SQL-Injections. I'd recommend setting smaller goals.

Comment: I intend to ultimately deploy it as a subscription based service to private patrol operators. I was just recently told about SQL injection by a friend of mine. That's something I'll be working on securing before deployment.

Comment: Given that my code is in JS and not Java, is that something I need to clarify in the headers?